# Obtaining 'Canonical name of object' that you see in the AD Object tab

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap

Trying to get the 'Canonical name of object' found in the Object tab of a users account in AD.

I can get the distinguishedName and cn attributes, but neither is in the correct format, for example:

I **don't** want: `CN=John Smith,OU=Users,OU=Organisation,OU=Tenants,DC=domain,DC=local`

I **do** want: `domain.local/Tenants/Organisation/Users/John Smith`

Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: Could be wrong, but I think one is constructed from the other

Comment: An ADUser object also has a `canonicalName` attribute you can ask for. Show us how you _"get the distinguishedName and cn attributes"_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up getting this working via:

```
public string getCanonicalName(string cDomain, string cUsername)
{
    string canonicalName = String.Empty;
    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, cDomain);
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, cUsername);
    using (DirectoryEntry de = user.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry)
    {
          de.RefreshCache(new string[] { "canonicalName" });
          canonicalName = de.Properties["canonicalName"].Value as string;
    }
            
    return canonicalName;
}
```